# pl.errorbar lolims on log log plot

Tags: python, logging, matplotlib

I am attempting to plot various points on a log log plot representing limits. I am using errorbar from matplotlib. However, the size of arrows varies from point to point. How can I generate limit arrows of constant size?

My code is as follows:

```
from math import pi
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

x_1 = np.arange(0.,10.)
y_1 = np.arange(11.,20.)

x_1_avg = np.sum(x_1)/len(x_1)
y_1_avg = np.sum(y_1)/len(y_1)

x_2 = np.arange(11.,20.)
y_2 = np.arange(21.,30.)

x_2_avg = np.sum(x_2)/len(x_2)
y_2_avg = np.sum(y_2)/len(y_2)


pl.yscale('log')
pl.xscale('log')
pl.errorbar(x_1_avg, y_1_avg, yerr = 2, color = 'g', lolims=-y_1_avg)
pl.errorbar(x_2_avg, y_2_avg, yerr = 2, color = 'r', lolims=-y_2_avg)
pl.savefig('test.eps')
pl.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you're using a log scale means that the length of a line on the plot will change based on where it's plotted. Also, `lolims` is a boolean, so I don't think you want to pass it a numerical value. Anyhow, you can compensate for the length change by using a value for yerr that is proportional to the y coordinate of the errorbar.

```
pl.errorbar(x_1_avg, y_1_avg, yerr = y_1_avg * .5, color = 'g', lolims=True)
pl.errorbar(x_2_avg, y_2_avg, yerr = y_2_avg * .5, color = 'r', lolims=True)
```

[image: Plot of arrows]

Comment: Is it possible to add a legend that shows the arrows properly?                           I have tried the following:                                                                                            pl.errorbar(x_1_avg,y_1_avg,xerr=None,yerr =y_1_avg* .175,fmt=None,ecolor='g', \
    lolims=True,capsize=3,elinewidth=1,mew=0,label='One')                                                       But the arrow head does not appear.